# an intutive explanation for the radon nikodym derivative

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, intuition

Can anyone please assist with an intuitive explanation for the Radon-Nikodym derivative in application to defining a set of probability measures for set(s)?

Comment: Do you mean a Radon-Nikodym derivative between different probability measures or in the context of random variables (i.e. between a probability measure and the lebesgue measure)?

Comment: between different probability measures, for example you have a reference probability measure and you want other probability measures "equivalent" to that using the Radon Nikodym derivative. Thanks

Comment: The R-N dervative of a measure $m$ with respect to another measure $m'$ is just a measure (!) of how different $m$ and $m'$ think set are.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez thanks, any intuitive explanation for equivalence of this measures such that m(A) =0 implies m'(A) = 0?

Answer (score 2):

One viewpoint that may help with the intuition is that the Radon-Nikodym derivative is ... well, in most cases, it's a *derivative*.  You know---derivative, like you first learned in kindergarten (or maybe freshman calculus).  It's not just an analogy, it's a real genuine limit of a familiar sort.

Chapter Eight in our text *Real Analysis* (Bruckner$^2$*Thomson) develops these ideas if you care to look.  You can download a PDF from [here](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/Free-Downloads.php).

Comment: wow...Thanks for the link,It'd sure be helpful